# Worklight - WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition or navigator.geolocation?

Tags: android, html, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

I try to get the location of the device, to show on google maps.
Currently I use the following code:

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                position.coords.latitude,
                                position.coords.longitude);
    ...
```

I just read Worklight has a WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition function.

What is the best to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing is fine.  THE WL.Device.geo api has a lot more that you can do than navigator.geolocation.  But if all you are doing is plotting your current location on a map, either api will do.